# Keep this build forever option - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I know there is a `Keep this build forever` button on Jenkins. I have a question with respect to this:

I have a configuration consisting of one main job and many sub-jobs (split across various phases). I would like to know if I click on the button in the main job, whether the artefacts in the sub-jobs are also stored permanently or not? Or should I go into each sub-job and keep clicking the button?

Comment: It'll be easier to know what's the end game, as in - why do you need to keep this build forever? This option is job based and not flow based, so you can't keep everything by doing that, but we can maybe help with what you want to achieve

Comment: I want all builds happening on Master branch to be stored forever. I have set it up such that i have separate build jobs (as sub-jobs) which run scripts for various build configurations. I need to archive all the artefacts of all these sub build jobs and store them permanently only for master branch as i always maintain it to be stable. The reason I want to keep them permanent is they are various releases of my development. I add new features with every commit i push into master.

Comment: So if I understood correctly - you need to archive the compiled artifacts, console outputs, etc. I'm guessing we're talking about different work-spaces as well so we won't be able to archive just the main job. You can leave "Discard Old Builds" unchecked and write a quick groovy script to remove builds without the "master" parameter in them. Again, not sure what your configuration is or how your flows are running.

Comment: Nope. I shall attempt to make it clear. All these jobs run in the same workspace. The main job triggers these sub-jobs when a commit is pushed into master. The workspaces get written with the new codes and then my build scripts, which is also cloned into the workspace, starts building it. This build is spread over many jobs and they all write the artefacts with different names to the same workspace.

Comment: Ok, so why won't you just archive the workspace and keep the main job? My first question was which information you'll need from the downstream jobs that you don't have in your main job? If everything is running on the same workspace the only thing that might be missing is the console output of the downstream jobs.... If that is not needed you really only have to keep the main job and archive the workspace.

Comment: Ok so when I click on `Keep this build forever`, I am actually just archiving the workspace contents after the build? So, it includes the source code which i checked out and also the build binaries that are created. Does it mean everything in the workspace will be archived? Because the post-build actions of my main job does not have any steps archiving anything. Only the downstream jobs do the archiving.

Comment: You're confusing 2 different things. When running a job in Jenkins you have 2 places the build is taking place - the Master machine and the slave machine it's running on. on the master you'll find the console outputs, job configuration, etc. on the slave you'll find the build artifacts, the sources, workspace, etc. Now: Keeping a build forever meaning to keep what you have on the MASTER and not on the slave, so it will NOT keep your workspace, artifacts, etc. The action of archiving is to upload the artifacts from the slave to the master machine, and then you can define and choose what to keep

Comment: The thing is - if you just want to keep the artifacts you've built, just archive in one place instead of several downstream jobs. you can ALSO archive in the main job from the same workspace to get the same result. another option which I highly recommend is to use a file repository instead like Nexus to keep your files. Either way - good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option only affects the current job.

If you want to keep your artifacts and build information for all the sub-jobs, you have to click on the "keep this build forever" for each one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Is there any documentation which tells this info or you got it through experience?

Comment: I did a test on my sandbox environment with a parent job launching a child job :)

Answer (score 2):

It is enough in each of the (sub) job's pipeline or groovy script to write
'currentBuild.rawBuild.keepLog(true)'

Comment: A little bit cleaner: `currentBuild.setKeepLog(true)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box solution.
You need a custom System Groovy script for this.

E.g. we do it this way:

- in our case, the main job copies artifacts from other jobs
- it writes the job names and build numbers of the copied artifacts into a .json file
- later we use this .json file in a System Groovy script to go through all jobs and set "keep forever" automatically