# Jenkins pipeline: propagate "keep this build forever" to downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there some option to propagate "keep this build forever" to jobs started by pipeline which I want to keep forever?

Now, this button works only on single job/pipeline. But if I need to keep the pipeline with its job I need to go every single job started by this pipeline and click on "keep this build forever"

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep this build forever option - Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412578/keep-this-build-forever-option-jenkins)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, because 1) the other answer suggests clicking and no automation of script 2) keep build forever plugin works only on freestyle jobs, not pipelines

Answer (score 5):

to clear this in the meantime the functionality has been added and you don't need to use rawBuild:

```
currentBuild.setKeepLog(true)
```

Comment: Other places ([e.g. this one](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/automatically-marking-jenkins-builds-as-keep-forever)) tell me to `keepLog(true)` rather than `setKeepLog(true)`. Is this a typo or do they work both the same?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
If used from within a pipeline, it is enough to write
'currentBuild.rawBuild.keepLog(true)'

Comment: but that solves your problem with propagating "Keep forever" to all downstream jobs?

Comment: Well yea, that 'clicks at the button' for me, and I can tie it to a build parameter.

Comment: Sorry don't get it. How downstream job is saved? You have to pass some parameters and run that command within the child job as well

Comment: Sorry, the point is, that when I write my own jobs that can run my own other jobs. I can modify the code that would set this keepLog to True however I wish, according to any streategy. It needs to be done before the job runs, of course, not after.